Avoid XLSX Sheetname Change when pasting data from Sheets with Google Apps Script
I have this Google Apps Script function to paste data into an XLSX file from my base sheet in Google Sheets. It works fine, but I have a problem. When the file.setContent() line is executed, the Excel file's sheet is automatically renamed to match the XLSX file name, including the .xlsx extension (the sheet gets renamed to interop.xlsx).
I need the sheet name not to change, or at least be able to control that name, because I am using MSExcelParser, and this parser does not return data when the sheet name contains dots.
I need to achieve this to fully automate the workflow I’m working on. What can I do?
    function overwriteXLSX(sheet, fileId) {
    
      var docSheet = sheet || SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Interoperabilidad');
    
      // Get Data Range
      var lastRow = docSheet.getLastRow();
      var lastColumn = docSheet.getLastColumn();
      
      var valuesRange = docSheet.getRange(1, 2, lastRow - 2, lastColumn - 1);
      var dataValues = valuesRange.getValues();
      
      // Clean Empty Rows
      valoresDatos = dataValues.filter(row => row.some(cell => cell !== ""));
    
      // Convert to TSV format (Tab-Separated Values)
      var tsvContent = dataValues.map(row => row.join("\t")).join("\n");
    
      // Generate Blob with TSV
      var blob = Utilities.newBlob(tsvContent, 'text/tab-separated-values', 'datos.tsv');
      
      // Get Google Drive XLSX File
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
      
      // Paste TSV in XLSX File
      file.setContent(blob.getDataAsString());
    }

dgs

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, how about the following modification?
From:
file.setContent(blob.getDataAsString());

To:
var sheetName = "sample"; // Please set your expected sheet name.
var orgName = file.getName();
file.setName(sheetName).setContent(blob.getDataAsString()).setName(orgName);

By this, when your script reflected this modification is run, the sheet name is set to sheetName instead of the original filename.
